# Entity Framework: Disabling EFCachingProvider For Stored Procedures

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

**EFCachingProvider** produces the following error when calling stored procedures:

> System.NotSupportedException: Command tree type
>   System.Data.Common.CommandTrees.DbFunctionCommandTree is not
>   supported.

But even if you create a separate context and don't set the **Cache** on it, the error still persists.

We have the following constructor on our **ObjectContext**:

```
public ExtendedEntities(string connectionString, params string[] wrapperProviders)
    : base(EntityConnectionWrapperUtils.CreateEntityConnectionWithWrappers(connectionString, wrapperProviders))
{
}
```

Most queries are successfully executed using the following:

```
ExtendedEntities context = new ExtendedEntities(settings.EntitiesConnectionString, "EFTracingProvider", "EFCachingProvider"))
context.Cache = ...;
context.CachingPolicy = ...;
```

The stored procedures calls are now using:

```
new ExtendedEntities(settings.EntitiesConnectionString, "EFTracingProvider");
```

And yet the issue persists?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider using the non-extended version of your Entities class to call the SPs as the wrapper doesn't like the command tree structure of the SPs.

In a case like yours I do the following:

using context as New MyEntities

```
context.DoSomethingHERE()
```

end using